# How to handle error thrown from custom global error handler in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-errorhandler

In angular 4, using custom error handler with the interceptor, everything working fine. below is the workflow.

below is the workflow in my best understanding how error being handled.

whenever a method call HTTP request ( using HttpClient) and the response comes as an error than

1. first it reach to the interceptor ( *error.interceptor.ts* )

   - here we check the error status .
   - based on status code, create new object `appError` which is instance of individual error class, for eg. `new AccessDenied(err.error))`
2. In this custom class ( *access-denined.ts* ), which extends `AppError` class

   - we call `super()` to use parent class method.

and than send this newly created error object using `throw Observable.error(appError)` from *error.interceptor.ts*

3. Now, this error handled by the `catch` block of the subscriber of the HTTP request in component `app.component.ts`

   - here we display the custom error message in HTML or we send an error to the next using `throw error`
4. Now this error will be handled by Global Error Handler ( *global-error-handler.ts* ) which extends Angular's  `ErrorHandler` interface

   - here we check again that whether this error is the instance of `AppError` or this is a system error and then handle the error here

#### app.module.ts

```
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler }
```

### app.component.ts

```
this.authService.myMethod(`url`).subscribe({
    (res) => { // successful response }
    , (err) => { 
        if(err instanceof AppError) {
            console.log('4. error display in html');
            this.errorMessage = err.message;
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    }
});
```

#### error.interceptor.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthFail, BadInput, NotFoundError, ServerError, AccessDenied } from '../errors/';
import { AuthService } from './../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private auth: AuthService;
    constructor(private router: Router, private injector: Injector) { }
    logout = false;
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
        return next.handle(req).catch((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            let appError;
            console.log('1. error comes in interceptor: ', err);
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch (err.status) {
                    case 401:
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                        appError = new AuthFail(err.error);
                        break;
                    case 400:
                        appError = new BadInput(err.error);
                        break;
                    case 403:
                        appError = new AccessDenied(err.error);
                        break;
                    case 500:
                        appError = new ServerError(err.error);
                        break;
                    default:
                        appError = new Error(err.error);
                }
                return Observable.throw(appError);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### access-denied.ts

```
import { AppError } from './app-error';

export class AccessDenied extends AppError {
    constructor(error?: any) {
        console.log('2. from interceptor', error);
        const msg = error.message || " Access Denied";
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

#### app-error.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class AppError {
    constructor(public message: string, public title: string = 'Error') { 
        console.log('3. parent class of custom error handler'); 
    }
}
```

#### global-error-handler.ts

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AppError } from './app-error';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
    constructor() {
        super(true);
    }

    public handleError(error: any): void {
        if (error instanceof AppError) {
            console.log('5. App Error handled here in last', error);
            // throw error;
            );
        } else {
            console.error('An exception occured. Please try again.');
            super.handleError(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my query is that if I write `throw error` in the `global-error-handler.ts` in if block than it display below error in console

> Uncaught  ( from file name Subscribe.js )

So how do we handle this error? I means if we write `throw error` from global error handler than how and where do we handle this?